# Syndrome or disease?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

Of late, I was reading about AIDS which is the abbreviation of "acquired immune deficiency syndrome". This got me into thinking that AIDS isn't a disease (a disease in itself). It is a set of specific symptoms or signs that are associated with a disease. So why we count it as a disease? Why in so many cases a disease has syndrome in the end of its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the technical medical jargon.  A syndrome is a collections of symptoms that seem to happen together.  Back in the early 1980s, doctors in America started noticing that young men were being hospitalised and dying with some similar diseases: particular cancers combined with severe forms of other diseases that the immune system would normally not have difficulty fighting.

At this time the reason was not known. It became clear that the common factor between these diseases was that the person had a weak (or deficient) immune system. And moreover, this weakness not congenital, you didn't have it from birth. Hence it could be "Acquired".

But the cause was not then known, only a description of the various symptoms. Hence it was a syndrome: a collection of symptoms that tend to occur together, and it was named the "Acquired Immune Deficiency Syndrome" or AIDS

Comment: I don't know much about medical history, but I'm wondering if other, lesser-known "syndromes" sometimes get renamed to "disorders" or "diseases," while more well-publicized syndromes (like AIDS) keep their original name just because they that name had worked its way so deeply into the public vernacular.

Answer (score 1):

AIDS is a disease that makes other diseases much worse.

The name includes the word syndrome for historical reasons.  A "[syndrome](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/syndrome)" is a collection of symptoms that occur together.  When doctors first notice such a collection of symptoms, they can call it a "syndrome", even if they have not proven that it is a communicable [disease](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disease) nor proven that it has an identifiable cause (or causes).